# Oleg Kononenko in Space Shuttle suit?

Tags: space-shuttle, russian-segment

I have seen a photo of Oleg Kononenko wearing the Space Shuttle flight suit, with the NASA badge on it. However, he never flew in the Shuttle, and there’s no mention on the Wikipedia page about him having been a backup for another astronaut/cosmonaut/spationaute.

[image]

Any idea where this photo comes from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Like many plans, the plan for Kononenko to fly on the shuttle was disrupted by the STS-107 accident in early 2003.

The picture of him in the ACES suit was taken in 2002, when he was assigned to Expedition 9, and supposed to fly to the ISS on STS-119.

> Veteran mission commander Steven W. Lindsey (Col., USAF) leads STS-119. The mission's pilot will be Mark E. Kelly (Cmdr., USN) with mission specialists Michael L. Gernhardt (Ph.D.) and Carlos I. Noriega (Lt. Col., USMC, ret.).
>
> Lindsey flew as the pilot on STS-87 in 1997 and STS-95 in 1998, and as mission commander aboard STS-104 in 2001. Kelly will be on his second Shuttle mission, having flown on STS-108 in 2001. Gernhardt will make his fifth mission to space. He served as a mission specialist on STS-69 in 1995, STS-83 in 1997, STS-94 in 1997, and STS-104 in 2001. Noriega was a mission specialist on STS-84 in 1997 and STS-97 in 2000, and he trained as the backup commander for Expedition Six.
>
> Expedition Eight commander C. Michael Foale (Ph.D.), flight engineers William S. McArthur (Col., USA, ret.) and cosmonaut Valery I. Tokarev (Col., Russian Air Force), will return from their stay aboard the Station.
>
> **Expedition Nine, Station commander Gennadi I. Padalka (Col., Russian Air Force), flight engineers E. Michael Fincke (Lt. Col., USAF) and cosmonaut Oleg D. Kononenko will travel to their home in space aboard STS-119.**

(emphasis mine)

[Astronauts Named for Future Space Station Missions](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/news/releases/2002/h02-249.html) dated December 12, 2002

The post-STS-107-failure [STS-119](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-119) had a completely different crew. It took one Expedition 18 ISS crewmember (Koichi Wakata) up and brought one down (Sandra Magnus), as well as performing ISS assembly tasks.

Comment: Thank you! :) Great answer! :)

Comment: @PierrePaquette you're welcome, and welcome to Space Stack Exchange.

Comment: Haha! Thanks… I’ve been lurking for a while… Might have commented a few questions, but never asked nor answered.